# How to notify my main activity, that thread has finihed?

Tags: android, multithreading, android-intent, android-activity, android-asynctask

I need to make simple thing: **from my app I have to make a photo, send it to server (in background) and show notification after sending**. It all works, but now I have to wait for end of sending file - activity with camera is closing after that. I don't want to wait, I want to get back to my main activity right after taking picture (but upload would be still going in thread, and send notification when finishes).

The problem: I don't know how to let know to my main activity, that thread has finished uploading of photo. 
Maybe passing context or handler to camera activity would help, but I can't do that by `putExtra()`.

Any suggestions?

Some fragments of my code:

in `MainActivity.java`:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, Camera.class);
startActivityForResult(intent, Constants.REQUESTCODE_CAMERA);
```

in `Camera.java:`

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    //(...)
    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);    
    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoUri);
    startActivityForResult(intent,TAKE_PHOTO);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    //(...)
    new SendFileToServer().execute();
    // finish(); // I would like to finish Camera.java here, and get back to MainActivity, while SendFileToServer uploads file and send some notification later
}

protected class SendFileToServer extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>{

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params){
        //(...) // here is sending of file to server, it works
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        //(...) // code below doesn't work, because I didn't pass "context", I don't know how, or it's just impossible
        MainActivity mainActivity = (MainActivity) context;                 
        mainActivity.sendFileName(filename);
    }

}
```

Comment: Please include your code of how you are doing the upload. You added the AsyncTask tag, so I assume you do the networking in an AsyncTask. You can override the onPostExecute method of your AsyncTask, which gets called when the task is finished, and runs on the UI thread, so you can do any view changes there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can do is send a broadcast on the end of the AsyncTask and register a receiver in the Activity where you want to do something (e.g. show notification).

To do that you will need to:

1) pass an Application Context to your AsyncTask (in Activity):

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    //(...)
    new SendFileToServer(getApplicationContext()).execute(); // pass application context to AsyncTask
    finish();
}
```

2) Send a broadcast from onPostExecute():

```
protected class SendFileToServer extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>{

    private Context context;

    public SendFileToServer(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params){
        //(...) // here is sending of file to server, it works
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        Intent intent = new Intent("com.example.UPLOAD_FINISHED");
        context.sendBroadcast(intent);
    }
}
```

3) Register a BroadcastReceiver in MainActivity (don't forget to unregister receiver in onPause()):

MainActivity.class

```
private BroadcastReceiver broadcastReceiver;

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter(
            "com.example.UPLOAD_FINISHED");
    broadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            // show notification
        }
    };
    registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, intentFilter);
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    unregisterReceiver(broadcastReceiver);
}
```

Comment: I didn't know about BroadcastReceiver - works great, thanks! :)

Comment: Although, it's been a long time since this answer was posted, I've downvoted it because in general BroadcastReceivers are being used when there is some sort of communication between the current app an other apps, or the OS. Please, refer to the official Android documentation https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcasts